# Can one use the Google APIs without GMS?

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-source

I plan to build a device that will use AOSP as operating system and will run a app for the interface. 
I know that I am allowed to use the APIs from https://developer.android.com/reference/packages.html.

Still the APIs from https://developers.google.com/android/reference/packages offer more flexibility.

May one use them without purchasing the [GMS package](https://www.android.com/gms/) from Google ?

(If this is not the place for the question please mention where should I move it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> May one use them without purchasing the GMS package from Google ?

No.

> I plan to build a device that will use AOSP as operating system and will run a app for the interface.

You may wish to consider using [Android Things](https://developer.android.com/things/hardware/index.html) instead, as that gives you a subset of the Play Services SDK's APIs.

Comment: I've checked Android Things but the licensing costs are not very clear. The Google APIs bring many features out of the box, thus making it easier to develop.

Comment: @florinx: "the licensing costs are not very clear" -- that is because it is still in a preview state. Google I|O is in two weeks; perhaps they will clarify matters there.